# Prisma Connection WhereInput for Array of enum values?

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, graphql-tag

Doing this

```
query {
  postsConnection(where: {
    status: PUBLISHED
  }) {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gives me `postsConnection` of published posts.

The `Post` model has an array of `Category` enum in field `categories`. This is the Post in `datamodel`

```
enum Category {
  TECH
  FIN
  DIGIMARK
  CODING
  TUTORIAL
  HOWTO
  WRITING
  INSPIRE
  SCIENCE
  POLITICS
  LIFESTYLE
}
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  editorSerializedOutput: Json!
  editorCurrentContent: Json!
  editorHtml: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  author: User
  authorId: String!
  categories: [Category!]!
  thumbnail: Json!
  status: PostStatus!
  slug: String!
}
```

***My question is, what Prisma Query do I need to write to get `PostConnection` of posts in a specific category?***

Comment: You already filter posts in your connection using `status: PUBLISHED`, you can do the same with `categories`

Comment: That's what the question is. I cannot do that with categories.. it is an array

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't quite understood the question, I added a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma doesn't yet allow filtering with Enum (see [issue on github](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1275))

You can however make a `to-many` relation with a new Type `Category` that you can create